# VB6 Paging using listview

Tags: vb6, paging

I'm thinking if there's a way (a component or reference) to breakdown an adodb.recordlist (e.g. records selected in sql database) consist of huge number of records.

Then a textbox can be used to jump by the user to jump into the page he wants to view.

Just wanna acquire an idea on how can i write this in codes.

Comment: Isn't that what a scroll bar is for? Ideally there would be a filter/search though, and with lots of items, maybe a virtual list view.?

Comment: @Deanna Thank you for your comment. I had already created in my code a filter/search textbox that search according to specified category. and I used listview in representing the records. What I did is that used  ADODB.recordset('recordset.AbsolutePage','recordset.PageCount' and recordset.PageSize). That three pieces of codes solved my problem. By the way. The purpose of pagination is to specify the number of page you desired to display when you are handling a huge number of records (say 10000 records) which is too cumbersome when you are scanning them with SCROLL BAR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the page size with the `.PageSize` property and jump to a specific page by setting the `.AbsolutePage` property.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an example.

Comment: thank you... you enlightened me by your answer.. I came up to this [site](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=882) which is more clearer but then your help is greatly appreciated.. how about a like for my question.. Hehehe